How to convert odd number of hex digits to bytes without loosing its leading zeros
How to convert with Python an odd number of hex digits to bytes without losing its leading zeros?
For example, string '0001000' should be converted to bytes 0001000

What does "bytes 0001000" mean, exactly?

You can use str.encode
s = '0001000'
b = str.encode(s)
print(b) # b'0001000'

If you want the leading \x you can use bytes.fromhex
s = '00010000'
b = bytes.fromhex(s)
print(b) # b'\x00\x01\x00\x00'

Keep in mined the string needs an even number of digits

How to get it with \x leading for each byte?

@DavidS Updated the answer, is that what you meant?
